# Oculus DK2 installation on Ubuntu 14.04 - cannot find ludev

Tags: linux, ubuntu, oculus

When I run the command, make from the 0.4.4 oculus linux package, I keep getting this error:

```
g++  -o ./Release/OculusWorldDemo_x86_64_Debug  ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/OculusWorldDemo_Scene.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/Player.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Util/RenderProfiler.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Util/OptionMenu.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Platform/Linux_Gamepad.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Platform/Linux_Platform.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Platform/Platform.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_Device.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_GL_Device.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_LoadTextureDDS.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_LoadTextureTGA.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../CommonSrc/Render/Render_XmlSceneLoader.o ./Obj/Linux/Debug/x86_64/../../3rdParty/TinyXml/tinyxml2.o -L../../LibOVR/Lib/Linux/Debug/x86_64 -lovr -ludev -lpthread -lGL -lX11 -lXrandr -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ludev
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Release/OculusWorldDemo_x86_64_Debug] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mo/software/oculus/ovr_sdk_linux_0.4.4/Samples/OculusWorldDemo'
make: *** [Samples/OculusWorldDemo/Release/OculusWorldDemo_x86_64_Debug] Error 2
```

What do I need to do to make Oculus work? I've had this for over 2 months now and haven't used yet because installation hasnt been possible to resolve.

Comment: Hint, the `-l` is the command line switch and `udev` is the name of the library (the `-ludev` will try to find a library file with name `libudev.a`), usually such a linkable development library `nnn` is in `nnn-dev` or `libnnn-dev` package in Ubuntu/Debian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the `libudev`and `libudev-dev` packages.

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev libudev0
```

Comment: Ok, i actually just noticed that thre is a script configuredebian that I haven't noticed before. How do I run a demo afterwards?

Comment: @momo I'm not sure about the configuredebian script or how to run a demo. I don't have an Oculus rift; I just know how to debug Linux.  It's worth learning that when the linker returns an error, the `-l` can usually be assumed to mean "library," which is how I immediately knew it couldn't find the `udev` library.  The `-dev` package contains the headers and other bits that might be needed for building.

Answer (score 1):

get ludev from http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/libudev0/download
download it, then install package with

```
sudo dpkg -i libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_i386.deb
```

you may have to do a

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev libudev0
```

for good measure
now you can do the make , make run